# read.df using sparkR but getting org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed error

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to read a JSON in my hdfs using the following:

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master = spark_link, sparkPackages = "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.0.3") 
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc) 
df <- read.df(sqlContext, "hdfs://somelocation/schema.json", "json")
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR r.RBackendHandler: loadDF on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: HDFS location is wrong it seems, try reading files locally like 'people <- read.df(sqlContext, "./examples/src/main/resources/people.json", "json")'

Comment: Well I used spark-shell and tried reading the same file using scala and it worked. I am guessing the issue is with R-Studio integration.